# python error on barcode generation

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using python 2.7 and pyBarcode 0.7 in Windows and I am trying to generate barcode as png image by using following sample code (available in pyBarcode webpage)

```
>>> import barcode
>>> barcode.PROVIDED_BARCODES
[u'code39', u'ean', u'ean13', u'ean8', u'gs1', u'gtin', u'isbn', u'isbn10',
 u'isbn13', u'issn', u'jan', u'pzn', u'upc', u'upca']
>>> EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('ean13')
>>> EAN
<class 'barcode.ean.EuropeanArticleNumber13'>
>>> ean = EAN(u'5901234123457')
>>> ean
<barcode.ean.EuropeanArticleNumber13 object at 0x00BE98F0>
# Example with PNG
>>> from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
>>> ean = EAN(u'5901234123457', writer=ImageWriter())
>>> fullname = ean.save('ean13_barcode')
```

Last line generates following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\barcode\base.py", line 68, in save
    output = self.render(options)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\barcode\ean.py", line 106, in render
    return Barcode.render(self, options)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\barcode\base.py", line 103, in render
    raw = Barcode.raw = self.writer.render(code)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\barcode\writer.py", line 188, in render
    self._callbacks['paint_text'](xpos, ypos)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\barcode\writer.py", line 280, in _paint_te
xt
    font = ImageFont.truetype(FONT, self.font_size * 2)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 218, in truetype
    return FreeTypeFont(filename, size, index, encoding)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 134, in __init__
    self.font = core.getfont(file, size, index, encoding)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 34, in __getattr__

    raise ImportError("The _imagingft C module is not installed")
ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed
```

I retried by installing Pillow (but before that I removed PIL); I downloaded "Pillow-4.2.1-win32-py2_7.exe" 
and I did also "pip install Pillow".

Now when I try to run

```
import barcode
```

I got:

```
  File "barcode\codex.py", line 12, in <module>

    from barcode.base import Barcode

  File "barcode\base.py", line 9, in <module>

    from barcode.writer import SVGWriter

  File "barcode\writer.py", line 12, in <module>

    import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 27, in <module>

    from . import VERSION, PILLOW_VERSION, _plugins

ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

What should I do ?

thanks

Comment: try that `pip uninstall pil; pip uninstall pillow; pip install pillow` @ernest-poldridge

Comment: I tried and I got the following error:   
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2606, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'pil;', 'at', ';')